# Delete entries of a specific time range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I want to delete from an existing table the entries that respond to a specific time range if they exist in this table, then calculate them and insert them to it. 
If they do not exist create them and just insert to the table.
How is that possible to be done? 
Could anyone give an example of this? 
The table structure should be the following:

```
create table test_table 
(
   [Date] float
  ,[UserName] nvarchar(max)
  ,[SessionType] int
  ,[Duration] float
  ,[MessageCount] int
)
```

Comment: `Date` should be `datetime` data type.

Comment: i want to compare the time range with Date column

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your query so we can help you fix it.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I do not think it should be data type, because float it is faster for big calculations

Answer (score 1):

if you have a Column that Stores the DATE and TIME then you can just delete the records based on that.

Suppose I have a Column Called CreateDate on My table. Then I can Delete all records Created between 10.00 am and 11.00 Today by Just Giving

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE 
CreateDate BETWEEN '2018-01-12 10:00:00.000' AND '2018-01-12 11:00:00.000'
```

Now Insert the values again using the Normal INSERT statement

Answer (score 1):

You can do in steps like this

First store the set of records in time range in a temp table

```
SELECT * INTO tempTable FROM YourTable WHERE CONVERT(FLOAT, [Date]) BETWEEN 43100.3603763503 AND 43110.3603763503
```

Then delete the records from the table

```
DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE CONVERT(FLOAT, [Date]) BETWEEN 43100.3603763503 AND 43110.3603763503
```

Then do the calculations as per your requirement with the data available in `tempTable` and insert the data into your table

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT * FROM tempTable
```

Then drop the tempTable

```
DROP TABLE tempTable
```

Comment: I tried your example and for some reason it applies the data from temp table 2 times in the table we want to keep. One in the position where it should be in the first place and one in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating my solution to this thank you all for help.

```
create mytable table 
(
   [Date] float
  ,[UserName] nvarchar(max)
  ,[SessionType] int
  ,[Duration] float
  ,[MessageCount] int
)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE [Date] >= 43082 AND [Date] < 43111)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE [Date] >= 43082 AND [Date]< 43111
;WITH Data AS (
/*do the calculation of data*/
)
INSERT INTO mytable select * from Data
END
ELSE
BEGIN
;WITH Data AS (
/*do the calculation of data*/
)
INSERT INTO mytable select * from Data
END
```